# Active Cloud Firestore database for a project programmatically / with PHP API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have access to a Google Cloud project with my service account in PHP and now i want to activate the Firestore DB of this project so i can use it. I know that i can set it up in the UI but is there a way to do it with the REST API / PHP SDK or any other API programmatically?

The error i get when i want to access the Firestore DB without activation:

```
{ "message": "The project XXXXX does not exist or it does not contain an active Cloud Datastore or Cloud Firestore database. Please visit http:\/\/console.cloud.google.com to create a project or https:\/\/console.cloud.google.com\/datastore\/setup?project=XXXXXXX to add a Cloud Datastore or Cloud Firestore database. Note that Cloud Datastore or Cloud Firestore always have an associated App Engine app and this app must not be disabled.", "code": 5, "status": "NOT_FOUND", "details": [] }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can now use the gcloud to create a Firestore database (*Alpha*), instead of doing it from the Cloud Console, as mentioned in this [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/133770824).

As the error message that you shared says, Cloud Datastore or Cloud Firestore *always* have an associated App Engine app and this app must not be disabled.

Create an App Engine app. Refer to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/create) for details:

```
gcloud app create --region=europe-west
```

Create a Firestore database. Refer to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/firestore/databases) for details:

```
gcloud alpha firestore databases create --region=europe-west
```